# Template files VS. HTML files in django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Hi i just have a broad question about the difference between template and HTML files in django. For example, in my project i have a directory called templates that will store my templates is this also where my HTML files would go? Are templates embedded in these HTML files? If not could you point me to a good example about how these two files work together? Thank you!

Comment: Templates generate HTML that is returned to the client. A template describes an html page and contains variables which are swapped out for content which makes them dynamic. HTML files are static files that just contain HTML. Nothing is done to them by django and they are returned by the server as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See chapter 4 in [the Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html).

Comment: Ok, but in what file is the first snippet supposed to be in?

Comment: It should go in a .py file that you create, but you have to register the function `current_datetime` in `urls.py`. That is explained in chapter 3. My advice is to start from chapter 1 to get a better understanding of what Django does, why it does it and how things fit together. The book is great